# Window Style for shading?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When a menu item or context menu is made, it has a shadow, if I create a window with WS_POPUP instead of WS_CHILD it has no shadow. How can I get the shadow? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enabled with WNDCLASSEX.style.  Turn on the [CS_DROPSHADOW style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176%28VS.85%29.aspx).  I think this only works on top-level windows.